# Second frame's panel after some work must return to parent frame's panel some responds

Tags: jframe, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I try to implement a create account frame with 3 options.
First JButton:  login user. it opens a new frame and prompts user to login.
Second JButton: create new user.
Third JButton Make order.

Every time you press a button a new JFrame opens and you do your work.
I can't find a way to make second Frame get some respond to first Frame.

For example, to return an object that i will use it to make third JButton visible, and to let user make an order.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this thread: ["Managing parent frame from child frame on java swing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573378/managing-parent-frame-from-child-frame-on-java-swing)

thanks for your responses!