# How to access components in a JFrame from an Internal frame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jinternalframe, jtogglebutton

I've created java Swing app where it consist of a jDesktoppane, inside it I'm loading/calling some jinternal frames from toggle buttons in the main frame (JFrame). And I've used jButton group to all the toggle buttons so only one frame will when a button is pressed.

Since I've used toggle button, even though I dispose a JInternalFrame the relevant toggle button will be in pressed mode (Selected). I've tried many ways and couldn't change the toggle-button's state from selected to UnSelected.

first i've created a method inside my Main JFrame.

```
public void buttongroup_off(){           
    buttonGroup 1.setSelected(null,false);             
}
```

Then I created an object inside the exit button of the JInternalFrame and through that I called the buttongroup_off() method.

```
private void jButton 7 ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
    Main m1= new Main();                         
    m1.buttongroup_off();                     
    this.dispose();                       
}
```

but it does not work!!, Can someone help me on this?
im kind a new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
    Main m1= new Main();                         
    m1.buttongroup_off();                     
    this.dispose();                       
}
```

In this code you are creating a **new** JFrame Main (which is invisible after creation) and disable its buttongroup. That is not what you want. You have to call buttongroup_off method using a reference to an existing Main instance. You may pass the reference via custom constructor for custom class that extends JInternalFrame, or you may add a static method to the Main class that will return reference to the Main instance. Like this:

```
private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
    Main m1 = Main.getInstance();                         
    m1.buttongroup_off();                     
    this.dispose();                       
}
```

You may also look at this question answers: [managing parent frame from child frame on java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573378/managing-parent-frame-from-child-frame-on-java-swing)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the JFrame by using code like:

```
Component source = (Component)event.getSource();
Main frame = (Main)SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( source );
```

Now that you have a reference to the frame you can invoke any method from your custom frame class.

Comment: Im getting an error in the 1st line of your code, *event* is the place.

Comment: The above code is added to you ActionListener. So use the variable name you use for the ActionEvent.

Comment: i didn't get you. whats the event's variable name?? 
is it actionPerformed??